# Complex analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let D be a simply connected domain. If f is analytic and **$f(z)\ne0$** on D, then prove that there exists analytic functions g( depending on n) **$\forall n\ge1$** such that **$g^n=f$**

I tried solving it the way I had solved for $ e^g=f $

For $e^g=f$, since $f(z)\ne0$ on D $f'/f$ has a anti-derivative say $h$ which is analytic since$f(z)\ne0\space\space\forall z\space\epsilon$ **C**

Let $c(z)=fe^-h$ Then $c'=e^-h(f'-fh')=0$ Hence $c(z)=constant=a\space\epsilon$ **C**

Then $a=fe^-h\Rightarrow f=ae^h$.    Let $a=e^b$ and $g(z)=b+h(z)$

Then $e^g=f$

Comment: This looks like a HW problem, what did you try to solve it?

Comment: Yes it is an assignment problem. I don't know how to proceed. I tried doing  in the same manner I had solved for e^g=f, but it is not helping.

Comment: How did you handle $e^g=f$?  I suggest you include this in the OP.

Comment: This is simpler than $e^h=f$ and reduces to it. Notice that  $(e^{h/n})^n=f$

Comment: Oh! How did I miss that? Thanks, Conifold.